# Accessing BITS client job properties via WMI in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, wmi, microsoft-bits

I see that there are WMI classes for BITS.  For example, BitsClientJob.  I have been unsuccessful in accessing these via vbscript and can find no online examples.

Does anyone know if listing BITS client jobs is possible via vbscript?

Comment: what about wscripting `powershell get-bitstransfer` with the `-Allusers` switch ?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819416.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the target systems and they may or may not have powershell on them.  I can also do this in batch using bitsadmin and have a script for that but I need more flexibility in what we are doing, hence wanting to move the entire task into VBscript.